# flutter run -> Error: No named parameter with the name 'keyboardDismissBehavior'

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

when I "flutter run"

Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
../../../Desktop/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pull_to_refresh-1.6
.4/lib/src/smart_refresher.dart:434:9: Error: No named parameter with the name
'keyboardDismissBehavior'.
keyboardDismissBehavior:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Desktop/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart:588:
9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const CustomScrollView({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target
'shared_preferences' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target
'path_provider' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target
'flutter_boost' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FMDB'
from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target
'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12

help me thanks

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Have you had any luck with solving this yet?

Answer (score 38):

`pull_to_refresh` plugin is not compatible with the current version of flutter.

**Solution:**
Change your `pull_to_refresh` plugin on your `pubspec.yaml` file from `1.6.4` or `^1.6.3` to `1.6.3` and run `flutter pub get`

FROM

`pull_to_refresh: ^1.6.3`

TO

`pull_to_refresh: 1.6.3`

Comment: thank you.but very strange,my pubspec.yaml file is pull_to_refresh: ^1.5.8,your answer solve my problem.

Comment: then it show this

flutter: FlutterBoost#onShownContainerChanged old:null now:default
flutter: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method flutterCanPopToNative on channel com.geelytech.oa/api)

can you help me?

Comment: FROM

pull_to_refresh: ^1.6.3

TO

pull_to_refresh: 1.6.3

this worked for me

Comment: For some weird reason, this worked for me. Can anyone explain to me what the sign (^) actually means / does please

Answer (score 7):

***Step 1:***

Edit file **pubspec.yaml**

FROM

`pull_to_refresh ^1.6.4` *or* `pull_to_refresh ^1.6.3`

TO

```
pull_to_refresh: 1.6.3
```

***Step 2:***

- run flutter clean
- Edit file **pubspec.lock**

  pull_to_refresh:

  ...

  version: "1.6.3"

more info: https://github.com/peng8350/flutter_pulltorefresh/issues/424

**UPDATE 05.03.2021**

For new version *flutter 2.0.1* -> You need to upgrade to `pull_to_refresh ^1.6.4`

Comment: thank you ,it works.but then when I flutter run ,it throw this,can you help me?

Xcode build done.                                           42.6s
vm-service: Error: Unhandled exception:
WebSocketException: Invalid WebSocket upgrade request
[VERBOSE-2:dart_isolate.cc(882)] Unhandled exception:
WebSocketException: Invalid WebSocket upgrade request
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to
http://127.0.0.1:59606/AoitBqsKfvo=/

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**: pin point your dependency version to 1.6.3:

`pull_to_refresh 1.6.3`

see [this issue](https://github.com/peng8350/flutter_pulltorefresh/issues/424).

The author made a mistake that he released a bugfix that is not suitable for current flutter release build.

Answer (score 0):

Change `pull_to_refresh` plugin to `1.6.3` and run flutter pub get