# Flutter Error: No named parameter with the name 'keyboardDismissBehavior'

Tags: flutter

The flutter project ran well on my android device before i ran flutter grade command. And then the project just cant run anyway without any code change. Here is the error message:

Launching lib/main.dart on RMX1971 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../env/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/pull_to_refresh-1.6.4/lib/src/smart_refresher.dart:434:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'keyboardDismissBehavior'.
keyboardDismissBehavior:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../env/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart:588:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const CustomScrollView({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/lgk/env/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 907
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/lgk/env/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Are you added `keyboardDismissBehavior` to  `CustomScrollView`? What is Flutter version?

Comment: @fartem it's 1.0.25+26 and i didnt actually add it to scrollview

Comment: Try to stop and rerun app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter run -> Error: No named parameter with the name 'keyboardDismissBehavior'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65838381/flutter-run-error-no-named-parameter-with-the-name-keyboarddismissbehavior)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a compatibility issue between `pull_to_refresh` plugin and the current version of Flutter during this time. There are some bugs related to this and most of the solutions were found on the thread:

- https://github.com/peng8350/flutter_pulltorefresh/issues/427
- https://github.com/peng8350/flutter_pulltorefresh/issues/424

To summarized the solution from this [thread](https://github.com/peng8350/flutter_pulltorefresh/issues/427#issuecomment-770335263):

> 1. **How to solve Error: No named parameter with the name 'keyboardDismissBehavior' ?**
>    to solve Error: No named parameter
>    with the name 'keyboardDismissBehavior' This error is caused due to
>    pull_to_refresh plugin that you are using in your flutter app is not
>    compatible with the current version of flutter. The solution is just
>    downgraded your plugin version.
> 2. **Error: No named parameter with the name 'keyboardDismissBehavior**
>    to solve Error: No named parameter with
>    the name 'keyboardDismissBehavior' This error is caused due to
>    pull_to_refresh plugin that you are using in your flutter app is not
>    compatible with the current version of flutter. The solution is just
>    downgraded your plugin version.
>
> ##### Solution 1
>
> This error is cause due to `pull_to_refresh` plugin that you are using
> in your flutter app that is not compatible with the current version of
> flutter. The solution is just to downgrade your plugin version. Just
> Follow below step to solve this error.
>
> 1. Edit file pubspec.yaml
> 2. Change This Line `pull_to_refresh ^1.6.4` or `pull_to_refresh ^1.6.3`
> 3. Replace with `pull_to_refresh 1.6.3`
> 4. run `flutter clean`
> 5. `flutter run`
>
> ##### Solution 2
>
> `pull_to_refresh` plugin is not compatible with the current version of
> flutter.